# Smartsheet API failed after switched to new laptop

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

```
import smartsheet.sheets
import smartsheet.folders

# Smartsheet client acess token
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet("api_key")
```

I recently switched my laptop, for some reason I am receiving error message as below every time I run above script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yuero\OneDrive - Amer Sports\Desktop\Work\Product Data Ops\Projects\Python Projects\excel2smartsheet\excel2smartsheet.py", line 8, in <module>       
    smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet("api_key")
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuero\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 167, in __init__
    self._session = pinned_session(pool_maxsize=max_connections)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yuero\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\smartsheet\session.py", line 56, in pinned_session
    total=1, method_whitelist=Retry.DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST.union(["POST"])       
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Retry' has no attribute 'DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST'
```

I can confirm that there is no issue with other scripts in my new laptop, and I am still able to run this program in old laptop, I can confirm that I have Smartsheet Python package setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suspect that this is happening because your new laptop has a newer version of the `urllib3` package installed than your previous laptop. Looks like `Retry.DEFAULT_METHOD_WHITELIST` was deprecated in version **1.26.0** of `urllib3` and removed altogether in version **2.0**. (See [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#200-2023-04-26) for history of that package).

I'd suggest that you try installing an older version of the `urllib3` package on your new laptop, to see if that fixes the problem. For what it's worth, I have version **1.26.2** of `urllib3` installed on my machine and am not having any issues using the Smartsheet Python SDK.